# Is there a reason this js breaks without the url prefix: www?

Tags: javascript, url, no-www

When I test this website, some of the javascript breaks and a checkbox won't mark itself when clicked if I'm using the url without the prefix: www.

It works fine if I do have the prefix there.

I'm not really asking for help on this specific websites problem, but does javascript need the url prefix to work properly?  Is it supposed to happen that some features break when the full url isn't there?

Comment: There's probably some other reason.

Comment: If you're on IE, you've probably got a wonky security zone definition and the non-www version is far more restricted than normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like something else is going on. Javascript Doesn't break just because the url you accessed doesnt have www prefixed to it.

Your web server could be behaving cause of some whacky setting. You could have some funky rewrite rules going on in your .htaccess file if its Apache your on. Or it could be something in the javascript thats looking for a hardcoded url or something.

So again, the answer would be no. A prefix on a URL does not in itself prevent Javascript from working properly.

Comment: yep, there is a hardcoded url referencing an image.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.example.org and http://example.org are two very different [domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name). Javascript needs a URI referencing an existing site to work.

Comment: Do most people buy both domains then?  Usually they appear to go to the same site.

Comment: Yes. See the "related questions" in the right column to find out "how to redirect from one domain to an other".